# How to resolve Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use the jQuery Autocomplete functionality, but I keep getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. I've done research and tried various things but it really doesn't want to work.

I've also gotten the uncaught typeerror: $(...).autocomplete is not a function error too.

I'm using the JQuery Library I have in my wwwroot folder since I have that already installed. I have tried deleting it and then using the script links online but it doesn't seem to work at all for me:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
@model Assig1.ViewModel.CitiesViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<head>
    <script>src= "~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"</script>
    <script> src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"</script>
</head>

<h1 class="alert-secondary p-2 text-center mb-3">Cities</h1>

@if (Model.RegionID != 0)
{
 <p>
    <a class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Countries" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@Model.RegionID">Return Back to Countries</a>
    </p>

}
else
{
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-success" asp-controller="Countries" asp-action="Index">Return Back to Countries</a>
    </p>
}


<form asp-controller="Cities" asp-action="Index">
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-3">
        <input type="text" id="SearchText" asp-for="SearchText" class="form-control" placeholder="City Name Search" title="Search Cities by Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

@if(Model.CityList.Count() > 0) {

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                City Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Country
            </th>
            <th>
                Region
            </th>
            <th>
                Air Quality Data
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


@foreach (var item in Model.CityList) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.CountryName)
                <br>
                <br>
                <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.ImageUrl)" class="card-img-top" alt="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.CountryName)" width="50" height="200" alt="@item.CityName" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country.Region.RegionName)
            </td>
            <td>
                Total Records: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AirRecordCount)
                <br>
                <br>
                Earliest Year: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EarliestYear)
                <br>
                <br>
                Latest Year: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LatestYear)
                <br>
                <br>
                <a class="btn btn-success" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@item.CityId" asp-route-countryID="@item.CountryId" asp-route-cityID="@item.CityId">Air Quality Data</a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
}
else {

    <div class="alert alert-danger text-dark text-center" >
        <h5>Sorry, no Cities found!</h5>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    var cityNames = [];

    @foreach (var city in Model.CityList)
    {
        <text>
            cityNames.push("@city.CityName");
        </text>
    }


    $(function () {
        $("#SearchText").autocomplete({
            source: cityNames
        });
    });

</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Dont put src attribute in tag, use  `<script src= "~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: And don't import multiple jquery, you can delete the second one.

Comment: `<script>src=` is not valid syntax. Including jquery 2x is also invalid.  If you're just starting out, start by copying the examples in the docs.  If the autocomplete library you are using is jQueryUI, [the autocomplete page](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) shows a simple example (click "*view source*").

Comment: `$ is not defined` = jquery not loaded *at the time that code runs*  `$(...).autocomplete` == jquery *is* loaded, but the autocomplete component (jquery-ui) is not loaded - or has been *unloaded* by loading a 2nd jquery.

Comment: It looks like you're using [tag:asp.net-mvc] - in which case the default "master" page (as it used to be called) is loading jquery for you - *at the end of the html*.   Open page, view source (not the .cshtml file).   For now, put *all* your scripts at the end of the page, not in `<head>` (until you know the difference)

Comment: @freedomn-m I did that and it now gives me the Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, I have a shared layout cshtml that is loading the jQuery at the bottom within the body tag is what I noticed.

Comment: Does your shared _layout include a `@section scripts`?  (I don't have exact code to hand) - if it does, add to your page `@sections scripts { <script src="..jquery-ui.js"></script><script>... any page specific script </script> }` then it should get rendered in the correct place.

Comment: Hi @softloftmaria, any updated here?

Answer (score 0):

Use src inside of the script tag

Assume jquery downloaded in your system

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

You can also use cdn for jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-+k1pnlgt4F1H8L7t3z95o3/KO+o78INEcXTbnoJQ/F2VqDVhWoaiVml/OEHv9HsVgxUaVW+IbiZPUJQfF/YxZw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You can select your jquery library version  [click here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, AutoComplete.js also need `jquery-ui.js`.

Secondly, If you use the Layout, please check your `Layout.cshtml`, be sure **there is no jquery.js reference**, then you can add reference in the `Index.cshtml`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If you use the Layout and do not want to remove the default `jquery.js` reference in `Layout.cshtml`, you need add reference in `@section Scripts{}`:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        //.........
        $(function () {
            $("#SearchText").autocomplete({
                source: cityNames
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```